# Lazy Line Painter - Rectangle not displaying correctly

Tags: json, svg

I'm currently trying to animate an image using the Lazy Line Painter, however, the some of the images are not displaying correctly. I have five rectangles on this image which are not closed, but for some reason the position of one of the corners is being displayed in the wrong place. The code which LLP has generated is below:

```
var pathObj = {
"floor-map": {
    "strokepath": [
        {
            "path": "M620.417,116.417l21.042-36.875  c0,0,29.188,16.313,52.188-2.854S712.667,37,712.667,37H755c0,0,2,48.833,51.5,48.833C851.5,83.333,852,37,852,37h41  c0,0-1.167,22.917,24.167,41.917l-20.833,35.708c0,0-21.5-13.063-48,0.771c-23,12.833-23.5,42.604-23.5,42.604H784  c0,0-1.5-48.75-48.167-48.75c-46.667,0-49.5,49.75-49.5,49.75H645C645,159,649.167,132.25,620.417,116.417z",
            "duration": 800
        },
        {
            "path": "M718.583,250.5l35.708-20.75  c0,0,13.521,24.708,44.021,23.042c30.5-1.667,39.51-24.479,39.51-24.479l36.172,20.01c0,0-14.164,27.672,1.503,50.839  C891.164,322.328,916,321.333,916,321.333V362c0,0-28.417,2.5-40.083,25.833L839.708,367.5c0,0,18.729-39-12.604-62.5  c-31.333-23.5-61.302-1.833-71.969,15.167l-35.318-20.833C719.818,299.333,733,278.167,718.583,250.5z",
            "duration": 800
        },
        {
            "path": "M761.75,419.917c0,0,22.875,13.292,47.542-0.042  l21.021,34.979c0,0-33.99,23.156-19.656,61.656c16.667,36.833,60.005,30.328,68.505,22.161l21.336,35.997  c0,0-22.499,10.665-23.499,43.665c1.813,29,19.641,39.52,22.968,41.238c0.344,0.178,0.533,0.261,0.533,0.261L880.333,696  c0,0-26.667-15-50.667,1.5s-21.5,41.5-21.5,41.5H766c0,0,3.667-26.25-23.667-41.917l20-36.458c0,0,61.333,18.938,70.5-29.229  c9.167-48.167-29-61.365-44.167-61.698c-15.167-0.333-26.833,7.318-26.833,7.318l-19.5-35.674c0,0,22-14.171,23.167-43.671  c1.167-29.5-24.5-41.335-24.5-41.335L761.75,419.917z",
            "duration": 1300
        },
        {
            "path": "M809.167,789.75c0,0,21.25,13.375,47.583,0.042  l21.458,35.688c0,0-25.042,14.521-23.708,43.521H813c0,0,0.667-30.25-24.833-42.75L809.167,789.75z",
            "duration": 600
        },
        {
            "path": "M 558,10 L 328,106 328,37 560,37 560,106   559,106 ",
            "duration": 600
        },
        {
            "path": "M 269,10 L 39,106 39,37 271,37 271,106   270,106 ",
            "duration": 600
        },
        {
            "path": "M 269,24 L 39,243 39,174 271,174 271,243   270,243 ",
            "duration": 600
        },
        {
            "path": "M 269,38 L 39,380 39,311 271,311 271,380   270,380 ",
            "duration": 600
        },
        {
            "path": "M 269,51 L 39,518 39,449 271,449 271,518   270,518 ",
            "duration": 600
        }
    ],
    "dimensions": {
        "width": 960,
        "height": 892
    }
}
};
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you simply forgot last symbol of every first Y coordinate of your rectangles.

```
var pathObj = {
    "floor-map": {
        "strokepath": [
        {
            "path": "M 558,106 L 328,106 328,37 560,37 560,106 559,106 ",
            "duration": 600
        },
        {
            "path": "M 269,106 L 39,106 39,37 271,37 271,106 270,106 ",
            "duration": 600
        },
        {
            "path": "M 269,243 L 39,243 39,174 271,174 271,243 270,243 ",
            "duration": 600
        },
        {
            "path": "M 269,380 L 39,380 39,311 271,311 271,380 270,380 ",
            "duration": 600
        },
        {
            "path": "M 269,518 L 39,518 39,449 271,449 271,518 270,518 ",
            "duration": 600
        }
        ],
        "dimensions": {
            "width": 960,
            "height": 892
        }
    }
}; 

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#floor-map').lazylinepainter({
        "svgData": pathObj,
        "strokeWidth": 1.5,
        "strokeColor": "#660"
    }).lazylinepainter('paint');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eZedP/

By the way, are you sure that you want to draw rectangles by five points instead of four? Cause this is what your code does.